# ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: A "user" or "key" was provided but could not be connected to a known cloud service

Tags: automation, mocha.js, webdriver-io

ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: A "user" or "key" was provided but could not be connected to a known cloud service (Sauce Labs, Browerstack, Testingbot or Lambdatest)
When I run My Code for Automation testing in WDIO then this Error is Happend How can I Solved this

In my code the capabilities is below in wdio.config.ts file

```
 capabilities: [{
        browserName: 'chrome',
        osVersion: '117.0.5938.149',
        platform: 'windows10',
        user : "USERNAME",
            key : "ACCESS_KEY",
            selenium_version :"3.14.0",
            browserVersion : "latest",
          
    }],
```